# How to create a viewModel object for many-to-many relationships

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm new to ASP.NET and currently working on a simple app to show a list of people and their hobbies. I have the following classes:

```
public class Hobby
{
    public int HobbyID                            {get;set;}
    public string Name                            {get;set;}
    public string Type                            {get;set;}
    public ICollection<PersonHobby> PersonHobbies {get;set;}
}

public class Person
{
    public int PersonID                           {get;set;}
    public int Age                                {get;set;}
    public string Name                            {get;set;}
    public ICollection<PersonHobby> PersonHobbies {get;set;}
}

public class PersonHobby
{
    public int PersonHobbyID                      {get;set;}
    public int PersonID                           {get;set;}
    public int HobbyID                            {get;set;}
}
```

When viewing a person's Details page, I also need to display their hobbies. I did some research and found that ViewModels are a good way to accomplish this. So I created one, but I'm not sure if I did it correctly:

```
public class PersonHobbiesViewModel
{
    public Person Person                          {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<PersonHobby> PersonHobbies {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<Hobby> Hobbies             {get;set;}
}
```

And at this point I know that I need to create a viewmodel object in my controller's Details method and populate it with data, but I don't know how to navigate through the different tables. I have this:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    var viewModel = new PersonHobbiesViewModel();
    viewModel.Person = db.Person.find(id);
    viewModel.Hobbies = ???

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

On the other hand, if I'm going in the completely wrong direction, let me know! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like the question is more about your data access than how your view models are constructed, what tech are you using to connect to your database? Entity Framework by any chance?

Comment: Yes, Entity Framework. I'll add it to the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@shenku's answer has correct way to map entities. But it is unnecessary if you don't consider about naming conventions.

Additionally Entity Framework has much of c#'s object oriented programming basics. That means if you pass the person object from your controller to view,  you could access to your entities on view like below.

```
//Controller
var person = db.People.Include(c => c.Hobbies).SingleOrDefault(x => x.PersonID == id);
return View(person);

@*View Page*@
@using Project.Models
@*  prints Person Name and Age  *@
@Model.Name @Model.age 
@*  prints Hobby Names of Person
 @foreach (var item in Model)
{                    
@item.name
}
```

You've answered your own problem correct as "circular reference" on your comment.

So you don't need `PersonHobby` class, Entity framework will automatically creates this table for you. This magic happens because you've defined hobby and person as a collection on their own classes.

Also you don't need a viewModel for your situation. Just pass the person or hobby object. Do not pass the Icollection because it's already loaded when you wrote `db.People.Include(c => c.Hobbies)`. Also you can define classes as 'virtual' so it will load entities without include method.(Lazy-loading)

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. I will come back to it when refactoring. :)

Comment: You're welcome! Please don't forget to mark as answer if it helped after your refactoring ;)

Answer (score 3):

Firstly what you might like to do, is change your entity models ever so slightly and let EF6 deal with the many to many complexity for you.

Your new model might look like this:

```
public class Hobby
{
    public int HobbyID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Hobby> Hobbies { get; set; }
}
```

Your context might be like:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Hobby> Hobbies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; } 

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Hobby>()
                    .HasRequired<Person>(s => s.Person)
                    .WithMany(s => s.Hobbies)
                    .HasForeignKey(s => s.PersonId);
    }
}
```

Then when you are creating your model you can simply query it like:

```
var person = db.People.Include(c => c.Hobbies).SingleOrDefault(x => x.PersonID == id);

var viewModel = new PersonHobbiesViewModel();

viewModel.Person = person;
viewModel.Hobbies = person.Hobbies;

return View(viewModel);
```

Have a read through the following tutorials about [complex entity models](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) and [reading from them](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/reading-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application), they cover the same content.

Ps. I have not tested any of this.

Comment: I did this, but now the resulting object is full of circular references. Person.Hobbies gets their hobbies, and then for each hobby, it also gets the people who have that hobby, and for each person it gets their hobbies, etc.